# JS - Intercept A Certain XMLHttpRequest And Fire a Function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am simply trying to fire a function based on a certain XMLHttpRequest being sent.  I don't need to change or add anything to the request - just trigger another function that is in my codebase.  The request is being sent by a website that is embedding my JS code.  I don't have control over the overarching site.  I have got the interceptor working for all calls, but I don't know enough about it to narrow it down by the below requirements.

```
Required - If the Request URL contains get-users
Required - If the Status Code: 200 
Optional - If the Request Method: GET
```

Not sure if I should be using the send and the send.call.

```
(function (send) {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (data) {
          console.log('Request', this);
          // If call url contains "get-users" && status code = 200 && possibly if the request method = get
          // {
          //   MyFunction()
          // }
          send.call(this, data);
        };
      })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a if condition to check if the request URL contains "get-users" and the status code is 200.

Like this below code :-

```js
(function (send) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (data) {
    console.log('Request', this);

    this.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200 && this.responseURL.includes('get-users')) {
        MyFunction();
      }
    };

    send.call(this, data);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Comment: on the request console.log I see that all the values for the if to pass are there... but the if still doesn't fire.  I put a log right after the other and the values log as 0, 1, and blank: console.log(this.readyState);
            console.log(this.status);
            console.log(this.responseURL);

Comment: please look again the above code I have just updated the above code. I added onreadystatechange